# upload image to root directory from sub directory php

Tags: php, file-upload

Hi I have this php which i need to change, I have made a duplicate of my site and stored it in a subdirectory called m/ I want to be able to upload files from the m/ directory site into the root directory site. this is the function for the script:

```
global $MAX_FILE_SIZE;

    global $MAX_THUMB_HEIGHT;

    global $MAX_THUMB_WIDTH;

    global $DELETE_ORIGIN_IMAGE;

    global $myfile;


    $err = check_err();
    if(!empty($err))
        return edit_profile_form($err);



    /*** Upload logo image*/

    if($_FILES['business_logo'])

    {
        //die($MAX_FILE_SIZE.'x');
        $business_logo=uploadfile("../img/consumer_user/",$_FILES['business_logo'],0,$MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    }

    if($business_logo=='-1')

    {

        $err['upload_logo'] = "<span style=\"color: red;\">- Upload error with <b>Business Logo</b>. Cannot be uploaded due to permission.</span><br>";

    }

    else if($business_logo=='0')

    {

        $err['upload_logo'] = "<span style=\"color: red;\">- Upload error with <b>Business Logo</b>. File type not allowed</span><br>";

    }

    else if($business_logo=='1')

    {

        $err['upload_logo'] = "<span style=\"color: red;\">- Upload error with <b>Business Logo</b>. File size not allowed</span><br>";

    }

    else if($business_logo=='2')

    {

        $business_logo="";

    }

    //echo $business_logo;

    if ($business_logo)

    {

        if($_FILES['business_logo']['name'])

        {

            $myfile=str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES['business_logo']['name']);

            $myfile=time()."_".$myfile;//echo $myfile;

            if ($myfile)

            {

                //Create thumbnail

                for($i=0;$i<count($MAX_THUMB_WIDTH);$i++)

                {

                    $MAX_QUALITY[$i]=$MAX_THUMB_WIDTH[$i]>$MAX_THUMB_HEIGHT[$i]?$MAX_THUMB_WIDTH[$i]:$MAX_THUMB_HEIGHT[$i];

                    thumbnail_images($_FILES['business_logo'],$MAX_THUMB_WIDTH[$i] ,$MAX_THUMB_HEIGHT[$i] ,"../img/consumer_user/","thumb_".$i,$myfile); 

                }

                if($DELETE_ORIGIN_IMAGE)

                {

                    deletefile("../img/consumer_user/".$myfile);

                }

            }

        }

    }
    if(!empty($err))
        return edit_profile_form($err);
```

as you can see I am trying to get out of the m/ by putting the obvious ../ but it doesnt seem to work.

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: And what happens? Uploads the file to a wrong directory or nothing?

Comment: nothing :/ unfortunately

Comment: Check if your directories are writable, you might not have access to write in them

Comment: Try to set the target as an absolute path first. Most times, the current working directory is not the directory your PHP file is in... when the absolute file works, find out what your working directory is: `getcwd()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no problem with accessing other directories, as long as your user has sufficient file access permissions.

Maybe try using a full file path `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]` and save your file with an absolute path?